# Python Regex Findall Lookahead

Tags: python, regex, findall

I've created a function which searches a protein string for an open reading frame. Here it is:

```
def orf_finder(seq,format):
    record = SeqIO.read(seq,format) #Reads in the sequence and tells biopython what format it is.
    string = [] #creates an empty list

    for i in range(3):
        string.append(record.seq[i:]) #creates a list of three lists, each holding a different reading frame.

        protein_string = [] #creates an empty list
        protein_string.append([str(i.translate()) for i in string]) #translates each list in 'string' and combines them into one long list
        regex = re.compile('M''[A-Z]'+r'*') #compiles a regular expression pattern: methionine, followed by any amino acid and ending with a stop codon.
        res = max(regex.findall(str(protein_string)), key=len) #res is a string of the longest translated orf in the sequence.
        print "The longest ORF (translated) is:\n\n",res,"\n"
        print "The first blast result for this protein is:\n"

        blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "nr", res)) #blasts the sequence and puts the results into a 'record object'.
        blast_record = blast_records.next()

        counter = 0 #the counter is a method for outputting the first blast record. After it is printed, the counter equals '1' and therefore the loop stops.
        for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
            for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                if counter < 1: #mechanism for stopping loop
                   print 'Sequence:', alignment.title
                   print 'Sength:', alignment.length
                   print 'E value:', hsp.expect
                   print 'Query:',hsp.query[0:]
                   print 'Match:',hsp.match[0:]
                   counter = 1
```

The only issue is, I don't think that my regex, `re.compile('M''[A-Z]'+r'*')`, does not find overlapping matches. I know that a lookahead clause, `?=`, might solve my problem, but I can't seem to implement it without returning an error.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

The code above uses biopython to read-in the DNA sequence, translate it and then searches for a protein readin frame; a sequence starting with 'M' and ending with '*'.

Comment: Your code is poorly indented. Try re-pasting with ``cat foo.py | sed -e "s/^/    /g" | pbcopy``

Comment: Most of the code is not relevant to the question. Please give some examples of input strings and the matches you wish from them.

Comment: The code takes in DNA sequences, like so: "ACTGGAACCTGTTTA", and translates them to protein sequences, like this: "MWDVIRSYPWHPTQMMGAPERGED*". I am looking for the longest string in the protein sequence that starts with the letter 'M' and ends with an asterisk '*'. That sequence can also contain 'M's. So I am looking for the longest distance between an 'M' and an asterisk, in short.

Comment: Only the longest string? You mentioned that you want to find overlapping matches. Please clarify. (What if there are multiple M's and multiple asterisks? Do you want multiple results and which ones?)

Comment: I want to findall all examples, overlapping and non overlapping, in order that I don't miss anything. Then, from that list, I'll take the maximum.

Comment: You can simply take the substring from first M to last asterisk. That is certainly the longest.

Comment: But might contain asterisks in the middle.  I'm not sure whether that would be okay for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.compile(r"M[A-Z]+\*")
```

Assuming that your searched string starts with 'M', followed by one or more upper case 'A-Z' and ends with an '*'.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what the input `MABCMDEF*GHI*` shall result in.  OP said _"looking for the longest string starting with M and finishing with *"_ on the one hand and _"The sequence can also contain M"_ (so, no asterisk inside allowed?).

Comment: No, no asterisk inside is allowed - anything is allowed inside, except an asterisk